# Loading font as resource fails in jar

Tags: java, fonts, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource, ioexception

I am using a custom font loaded from a resource. This code works perfectly within Eclipse, but gives an error when run as a jar.

```
try {
     java.io.InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/xkcd.ttf");
     iybfont = Font.createFont(Font.PLAIN, inputStream); //CRASHES ON THIS LINE
 } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

When run as a jar, it gives the following error (from a command prompt window):

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
    at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at vbday.Start.initialize(Start.java:83)
    at vbday.Start.<init>(Start.java:45)
    at vbday.Start.main(Start.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

Line 83 is shown in the comment above

Comment: @AndrewThompson the rest is mostly unrelated to the actual problem at hand. I'll keep things like layout managers in mind for next time, but they are currently irrelevant to the problem at hand

Comment: OH! whoops, I did not realize that the font loading was actually failing and the println what was generating part of the error message. I will update the error code with the stacktrace tomorrow! So I suppose the real problem is that the font resource is not loading in a jar

Comment: @AndrewThompson alright, I've made major edits to the question including adding the stacktrace and removing irrelevant code. As far as I can tell the filepath is correct. (It loads in eclipse, after all)

Comment: gah, nevermind. figured it out. the extention should be ".TTF" not ".ttf". Thank you for your guidance in helping me figure out the actual problem

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with filename case. Eclipse corrects for wrong case in extensions apparently, but the final jar does not.

Changed `.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/xkcd.ttf");` to `.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/xkcd.TTF");`

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Plus one for reporting back.